# Поворот кнопки WPF C# кодом

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу при клике вращать кнопку.
Подумал, что должно так работать:

```
void new_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        var transform = btn.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
        transform.Angle += 90;
    }
```

Но не работает)) Что не так? Хочу поворот реализовать именно C# кодом, не XAML.
При клике ругается на эту строку:

```
transform.Angle += 90;
```

Исключение:

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из Вашего кода получается, что в этой строке:

```
var transform = btn.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
```

получаем значение `null`, поэтому далее получаем исключение *Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта* при обращении к `transform.Angle`. Поэтому следует добавить проверку, а затем уже поворот, попробуйте так:

```
void new_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if(btn != null)
    { 
        var rotateTransform = btn.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
        var transform = new RotateTransform(90 + (rotateTransform?.Angle ?? 0));
        btn.RenderTransform = transform;
    }
}
```

В данном примере кнопка поворачивается на 90 градусов после каждого нажатия.

Полезные ссылки:

1. [Transforms Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Свойство UIElement.RenderTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [How to: Rotate an Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754009(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Повернулось, но только один раз: при повторном нажатии ничего не происходит. Хотелось бы чтобы вращалось при каждом нажатии, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Comment: @Saint, чтобы поворачивалось больше(меньше) меняйте значение внутри конструктора `RotateTransform` на нужное Вам

Comment: а такой ещё вопрос: как сделать вращение относительно центра? А то если развернуть на 180, то кнопка вообще отворачивается в другую сторону. То есть, как я понимаю, разворот сейчас осуществляется относительно левого верхнего края кнопки.

Comment: @Saint, вот тут достаточно подробно написано [Практическое руководство. Вращение объекта](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms754009(v=vs.110).aspx), нужно установить центр поворота.

Comment: @Saint, так Вам же нужно увеличивать угол. А Вы все время один и тот же угол пишете, вот она на месте и стоит. Откройте третью ссылку в ответе, в комментарии я прикрепил ту же самую, только на русском. Сейчас дам ссылку.

Comment: тут всё описано на XAML, просто проблема в том, что у  меня кнопки генерируются, а не прописываются в XAML, что усложняет мою ситуацию :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46140/discussion-between-denis-bubnov-and-saint).